# Is it possible to remove the column group rows from the excel export and just get the flat data

Tags: excel, ag-grid

I don't want the row groups with arrows to show up in excel. I just need to group by two columns and show flat data in excel if that makes sense. Ag grid keeps adding arrows

eg

```
FACTORY | CARS | Total
Detroit    X      10
Detroit    Y      5
Ney York   X      8 
New York   Z      10
```

This should be easy, maybe I am missing something?

Comment: have you tried using skipGroups: true in params ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `skipGroups : true` in params.

```
this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({skipGroups : true})
```

As per docs -

> **skipGroups**
>      Set to true to skip row group headers and footers if grouping rows. No impact if not grouping rows. Default: false

[Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#example-selecting-data-to-export) from docs.